# How do I write generic implicit conversion?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit-conversion, spray

Could you please help me write generic implicit conversion ?

I'm using Scala 2.10.2 and Spray 1.2.

Here is what I have

```
// for "parameters"
implicit def ObjectIdUnmarshallerString = new Deserializer[String, ObjectId] {
  def apply(value: String) =
    try Right(new ObjectId(value))
    catch {
      case ex: Throwable => Left(MalformedContent(s"Cannot parse: $value", ex))
    }
}

//  for "formParameters"
implicit def ObjectIdUnmarshallerHttpEntity = new Deserializer[HttpEntity, ObjectId] {
  def apply(value: HttpEntity) = ObjectIdUnmarshallerString(value.asString)
}
```

As you can see deserializer for HttpEntity->ObjectId simply uses String->ObjectId deserializer. I have to copy-paste such code for every class I use in HTTP routing trait.

So I thought what if I can write generic HttpEntity->T which will use `Deserializer[String, T]` available in scope.

I tried this:

```
  implicit def GenericUnmarshallerHttpEntity[T] = new Deserializer[HttpEntity, T] {
    def convertAsString(value: HttpEntity)(implicit conv: Deserializer[String, T]) = conv(value.asString)

    def apply(value: HttpEntity) = convertAsString(value)
  }
```

Sadly it doesn't work. And says:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter conv: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[String,T]
    def apply(value: HttpEntity) = convertAsString(value)
                                                  ^

not enough arguments for method convertAsString: (implicit conv: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserializer[String,T])spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserialized[T].
Unspecified value parameter conv.
    def apply(value: HttpEntity) = convertAsString(value)
                                                  ^
```

Could you please suggest how to do it ?

Comment: try `implicit def GenericUnmarshallerHttpEntity[T](implicit conv: Deserializer[String, T]) = ...` and remove implicit param from `converAsString`

Comment: @LuigiPlinge It helped ! Could you please paste your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `implicit def GenericUnmarshallerHttpEntity[T](implicit conv: Deserializer[String, T]) = ...` and remove implicit param from `convertAsString`.

As it stands in the question, `apply` has no requirement for the implicit to be in scope, so it can't call the `convertAsString` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your apply function needs to have the implicit passed through to the convert method

```
implicit def GenericUnmarshallerHttpEntity[T] = new Deserializer[HttpEntity, T] {
  def convertAsString(value: HttpEntity)(implicit conv: Deserializer[String, T]) = conv(value.asString)

  def apply(value: HttpEntity)(implicit conv: Deserializer[String, T]) = convertAsString(value)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that. Compiler says `object creation impossible, since method apply in trait Function1 of type (v1: spray.http.HttpEntity)spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Deserialized[T] is not defined
(Note that T1 does not match spray.http.HttpEntity)
  implicit def GenericUnmarshallerHttpEntity[T] = new Deserializer[HttpEntity, T] {
                                                      ^`